# Why does the pop up disappear upon check box click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, webforms

I have used panel inside template field and it disappears when I check a checkbox.

I tried fixing it but still disappears. The code works good while debugging but apparently not. Please help if you can. I have spent a lot of time on it already.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText='Finalized ?'>
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="btnFinalizedRecord" OnClick="btnFinalizedRecord_Click" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsFinalized")) == true? "Already Finalized": "Finalize" %>'
                                CssClass="" ToolTip="Finalize" CommandName="Finalize"
                                CommandArgument='<%#Eval("IsFinalized")%>' Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsFinalized")) == true? false: true %>'></asp:LinkButton>
     <ajax:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender1" runat="server" DisplayModalPopupID="mpe2" TargetControlID="btnFinalizedRecord">
     </ajax:ConfirmButtonExtender>
     <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe2" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopup2" TargetControlID="btnFinalizedRecord" OkControlID="btnYes"
                                CancelControlID="btnNo" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
      </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
      <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup2" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
      <div class="header">
        Confirmation
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        Are you sure to <b>Finalize</b>? 
       <asp:CheckBox ID="chkConfirmFinalize" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkConfirmFinalize_CheckedChanged" />
        <br />
        You will not be able to perform an edit after finalizing.
      </div>                                        
      <div class="Popupfooter" align="right">
       <asp:Button ID="btnYes" Enabled="false" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-danger" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
       <asp:Button ID="btnNo" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-primary" runat="server" Text="No" />
      </div>
     </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

.cs:

```
    protected void chkConfirmFinalize_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var chkConfirmFinalize = sender as CheckBox;
            GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)chkConfirmFinalize.NamingContainer;
            Panel pnlPopup2 = gr.FindControl("pnlPopup2") as Panel;
            if (chkConfirmFinalize.Checked == true)
            {
                btnYes.Visible = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                btnYes.Visible = false;
            }
            pnlPopup2.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.Msg_Error(Master, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `<asp:CheckBox ID="chkConfirmFinalize" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkConfirmFinalize_CheckedChanged" />` Maybe your AutoPostBack causes it to refresh?

Comment: yes i know that, i want a solution.

Answer (score 0):

With AutoPostBack you are reloading the page (going to the server and back) when the checkbox, that is why the panel disappear. 
You should try to use javascript with the "onclick" event.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkConfirmFinalize" runat="server" OnClick="somefunction(this)" />
```

And display the button in jquery:

```
function somefunction(element) {
    if ($element.val() == true) {
        $("#btnYes").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $("#btnYes").prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```